# How to search a NSDictionary object from a NSMutableArray using a value of a key in dictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an array which contains `NSDictionaries`.

```
[
  {
    "ObjectId": 20,
    "ObjectName": "Leave Request",
    "RequestItems": []
    "ClassName": "req-auth"
  },
  {
    "ObjectId": 22,
    "ObjectName": "Cancel Leave Request",
    "RequestItems": []
    "ClassName": "req-auth"
  }
```

I want to check in this array `Leave Request` and `Cancel Leave Request` objects are available. So I am going to search the object by `ObjectName`. But I don't understand how to search these objects by using a 1 value of those objects. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: your issue related question have been answered multiple times on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *searchString = @"Cancel";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [evaluatedObject[@"ObjectName"] localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:searchString];
}];
    filteredContentList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[searchListValue filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `NSPredicate`. Something like this:

```
-(NSArray *)array:(NSArray *)array filteredWithString:(NSString *)string{

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.ObjectName CONTAINS[cd] %@",string];

    return [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Just pass in the array to filter with the string you wish to filter it by and call it where you want to filter it.

**A few things:** Here `cd` is used to perform a case insensitive compare, if you want it be case sensitive just remove the `cd` from the string. `ObjectName` is the property you wish to filter by. You can change `CONTAINS` to `LIKE` if you want an exact comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fetch `objectName` from each dictionary in array, then do it like:

```
   for dict in arrayOfData{
        if let strObjectName : String = dict["ObjectName"] as? String{
        print(strObjectName)
        }
   }
```

Comment: You can create a function where in a string is passed for OP to get only the values he wants inside `ObjectName`. Then use this string inside a where clause making it to be  `if let strObjectName = dict["ObjectName"] as? String, strObjectName.contains("Cancel")` and then append the dictionary in a new array